# Is chremamorphism the literary technique for objectification?

Tags: meaning, literary-techniques, literary-device

So I was hoping if someone could support that chremamorphism is the literary technique term for objectification. Specifically, I am looking at the phrase "the pushing of your sadness". Sadness, a personal attribute, is being depicted as an object which I think aligns with chremamorphism. Am I misunderstanding the technique, or is there a better term for the concept of objectification in literature?

Comment: The only words starting with *chrema-* that I could find with a quick search had to to with finance or money. Do you have a reference for *chremamorphism*?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty https://www.slaphappylarry.com/animalification-personification/#:~:text=Chremamorphism%20is%20the%20literary%20technique,be%20compared%20to%20a%20flower.

Comment: I had only looked in dictionaries at onelook.com. A general search finds a lot of support for *chremamorphism* in the sense you mention. Maybe someone with a better dictionary (OED, for example?) could look it up.

Comment: OED: **No dictionary entries found for ‘chremamorphism’**. Find ‘chremamorphism’ in: » phrases (0) definitions (0) etymologies (0) quotations (0) full text (0), From Google Books: Inner Purity and Pollution in Greek Religion: Early Greek religion By A & I Petrovic: The labels Empedocles uses are revealing, ... chrema is an oracle, and psephisma is a decree. -- The Therapeutic Interview in Mental Health 2017
DörrZegers (1995) talks about this in terms of a “chrematic transformation” (chrema = corpse) Chrema is the inanimate nature to which the melancholic's body is reduced. **Don't use it.**

Comment: @Greybeard That's an answer. Please use the answer box for answers.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Basic research needs to be shown even where it leads to what may be considered an inadequate answer.

Comment: 'Concretisation' exists, but I think has a non-sufficiently overlapping range of meaning. It's usually an event etc 'substantiating' / 'embodying' a concept or belief.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm not at all sure that it is. It is a response to Jack O'Flaherty's request for an OED search, and absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. The OED is never up to date. The Google books reference give what appear to be conflicting opinions as to what a "chrema" is but do not mention "chremamorphism"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What figure of speech takes the form "\[concrete noun\] of \[abstract noun\]" (non-anthropomorphic)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247189/what-figure-of-speech-takes-the-form-concrete-noun-of-abstract-noun-non-a)

Answer (score 2):

There is no OED entry for ‘chremamorphism’. Even the request to find ‘chremamorphism’ in the OED's phrases (0) definitions (0) etymologies (0) quotations (0) full text (0), gives a nil result.

From Google Books we have:

"Inner Purity and Pollution in Greek Religion: Early Greek religion" By A & I Petrovic, we have

> The labels Empedocles uses are revealing, ... chrema is an oracle, and psephisma is a decree.

Whereas in "The Therapeutic Interview in Mental Health 2017" we have

> Dörr Zegers (1995) talks about this in terms of a “chrematic transformation” (chrema = corpse) Chrema is the inanimate nature to which the melancholic's body is reduced."

The conclusion must be: Don't use *chremamorphism*.

Comment: It might not be the up-to-date answer omniscience could give, but 'the conclusion must be: _Don't use "chremamorphism"_ ' after lack of reasonable evidence turned up in sensible research seems the acceptable answer short of this.